# JavaFX TabPane Tab select from foreign Controller

Tags: java, javafx, tabpanel

after I changed my code with lead of this helpful post ([PASSING PARAMETERS JAVAFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)) my setTab function works not really. Its gets called but doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Controller1 controller1 = new Controller1();
        controller1.showStage();
  }
}
```

Controller1.java

```
public class Controller1{

    private final Stage thisStage;
    private Controller2 controller2 = new Controller2(this);

    public Controller1() {
    thisStage = new Stage();

    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Steuerung.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        thisStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
        thisStage.setTitle("Steuerung");
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    public void showStage(){ thisStage.show();}

    @FXML private void initialize() {
        b_AnzeigeÖffnen.setOnAction(e -> openAnzeige());
        b_Ecke.setOnMouseClicked(e -> controller2.setTab(2));
    }

    private void openAnzeige(){
        Controller2 controller2 = new Controller2(this);
        controller2.showStage();
    }

    @FXML
    private Label b_Ecke;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem b_AnzeigeÖffnen

}
```

Controller2.java

```
public class Controller2 {

private Stage thisStage;

private final Controller1 controller1;

public Controller2(Controller1 controller1) {
    this.controller1 = controller1;
    thisStage = new Stage();
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Anzeige.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        thisStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
        thisStage.setTitle("Spielstand");

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void showStage() { thisStage.show();}


@FXML
private TabPane TP_A;

@FXML
private Tab tA_Home;

@FXML
private Tab tA_EckePreview;

@FXML
private Tab tA_EckVerhältnis;

@FXML
private Tab tA_Spielverlauf;

@FXML
private Tab tA_Spielstatistik;

@FXML
private Tab tA_GelbeKarte;

@FXML
private Tab tA_RoteKarte;

@FXML
private Tab tA_Elfmeter;

@FXML
private Tab tA_Auswechselung;


@FXML public void setTab(Integer i) {
   System.out.println("TABSWITCH");
    switch(i) {
        case 1: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_Home); break;
        case 2: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_EckePreview); break;
        case 3: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_EckVerhältnis); break;
        case 4: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_Spielverlauf); break;
        case 5: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_Spielstatistik); break;
        case 6: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_GelbeKarte); break;
        case 7: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_RoteKarte); break;
        case 8: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_Elfmeter); break;
        case 9: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_Auswechselung); break;
        //case 10: TP_A.getSelectionModel().select(tA_Nachspielzeit/Verlängerung); break; -> TODO
        default: System.out.println("Fehler: Tab in TP_A nicht vorhanden!"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

> !packages and imports are removed bc of Body length!
>
> I know that I have to rewrite the last few functions as they could easy be one.

Steuerung.fxml and Anzeige.fxml would be to long. If u want to see them tho, here is the complete GitLab project.
[GitLab Project](https://gitlab.com/t0mbrn/ProjektSpielstand)

> Sorry for the German comments, function/var names and or objects

Thans for ur advice!

> Edit: Grammar

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__, just a minimal ui, a single button that should be triggered and still complete, must be reproducible that is contain controller, fxml, boilerplate app. And unrelated: java naming conventions please!

Comment: The `Controller2` instance on which you call `setTab()` is not the instance on which you called `showStage()`, so you won't see any effect.

Comment: Count you please tell me, what i should change then? Im kinda new in JavaFX.

Comment: *Could you please tell me

Comment: Well, it depends what behavior you want. If you want a new `Controller2` instance every time the `b_AnzeigeÖffnen` button is pressed, then you need to create a new instance (as you currently do), but save it in the instance variable. If you just want to show the instance you already created (i.e. show or re-show the same one each time), then don't create a new instance in that event handler.

Comment: could you give me a code example how to do that if I don't want to create a new instance every time? or maybe a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Controller1` you create a `Controller2` instance as an instance variable:

```
private Controller2 controller2 = new Controller2(this);
```

and when the user clicks on the `b_Ecke` label, you change the tab in that instance:

```
b_Ecke.setOnMouseClicked(e -> controller2.setTab(2));
```

However, there is nowhere in your code where you ever call `showStage` on that instance of `Controller2`, so you are changing the tab selection in something that is not displayed.

When the user selects the `b_AnzeigeÖffnen` menu item, you create a *new* `Controller2` instance, and display that instance:

```
b_AnzeigeÖffnen.setOnAction(e -> openAnzeige());

private void openAnzeige(){
    Controller2 controller2 = new Controller2(this);
    controller2.showStage();
}
```

Instead, just display the `Controller2` instance you have already created:

```
b_AnzeigeÖffnen.setOnAction(e -> openAnzeige());

private void openAnzeige(){
    // Controller2 controller2 = new Controller2(this);
    controller2.showStage();
}
```